# MYSQL, como obtener los datos de la tabla a través de subconsulta

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando una consulta en la que consiste en obtener los datos de quien tenga el id mayor y a la vez que sea el mismo numero de habitacion:

```
public static function getpreviousproduct($room) {

    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `finished_products` WHERE `room`=:room AND `ID` = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `finished_products` WHERE `room`=:room ");
    $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);

    return $row = $query->(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
}
```

he cambiado la consulta miles de veces pero no me obtiene los datos, ademas de que a la hora de devolver el array me lo devuelve vacio, no se por que.

para estar mas claro en la base de datos hay varios productos de la habitacion 158, y cada uno tiene un id, quiero obtener los datos del que tenga el mayor id de la misma habitacion, ayuda please :(

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si estas respuestas han aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarlas para que también puedan ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

No obtienes resultados porque te faltaba un paréntesis al final del query y una de las condiciones te sobraba:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `finished_products`
  WHERE `ID` = (
    SELECT MAX(ID) 
      FROM `finished_products` 
      WHERE `room`=:room
  );
```

El `MAX(ID)` ya escogerá un `ID` de la habitación que te interesa, no es necesario hacer esa comprobación dos veces.

Por lo demás, parece tener buena pinta, ya casi lo tenías.

Comment: me di cuenta ya, pero aun poniendo todos los parentesis igual no me agarra la condicion, solamente funciona con el ID mayor, pero al agregarle el AND room =: room no funciona

Comment: Ok, prueba así. Realmente ya tienes incluida esa condición en la subconsulta

Answer (score 0):

public static function getpreviousproduct($room) {

```
    $query = self::connect()->prepare(("SELECT * FROM `finished_products` WHERE `ID` = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `finished_products`) AND `room` =: room"));
    $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);

    return $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
}
```

aqui el arreglo, pero aun asi no

Comment: Hola @plus, la consulta no te va a devolver lo que esperas, pues el `MAX()` lo estás obteniendo de TODAS las habitaciones, no de la que le interesa al OP